# Specify what version of Meteor to use locally

Tags: meteor

So I'm just having a look at someone's code and downloaded it to try and run locally. The problem is that they last updated the project in April so they're not using the latest version of meteor but my localhost is trying to do just that.

I read there was a way to specify what version of Meteor would run locally (and subsequently package) but I can't find it again for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meteor update --release 0.6.4.1
```

Answer (score 4):

To set the version for the current project only, write the number in `.meteor/release` text file.