# Deploy Meteor code using a different version of Meteor?

Tags: deployment, meteor, cloud9-ide

I'm developing a Meteor app on cloud9 (c9.io) which is stuck on Meteor v0.5.9.
I'd like to try my app with 0.6.5.1 as I'm having a few unexplained issues.

Q: Is it possible to do a 
   meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com

and specify the **version** of Meteor.

I'm assuming not, as I guess everything's packaged up and deployed together, including Meteor itself?

[Specify what version of Meteor to use locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534727/specify-what-version-of-meteor-to-use-locally) suggest you can specify meteor versions, so may be I should set that just before deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it's the same argument as in the other question:

```
meteor deploy --release <tag of meteor> myapp.meteor.com
```

The tags are the same as in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases but without the `release/` prefix.

However, in your case, the current version is 0.6.5.1 so if you just did a `meteor update` on your machine, that would be the default release for any deploy or bundling. Beware that it will be hard to go back to a previous version because of the various changes it will make.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. the c9 install of meteor is slightly different to the stand one, so `meteor update` screws things up. So I went with `meteor deploy --release 0.6.5.1 myapp.meteor.com`. NOw I just need to figure out how to display the version number on my page.